# DefaultTableModel set column class at creation

Tags: java, jdbc, jtable, extends, defaulttablemodel

Currently I got the following problem:

I load the TableModel data from a H2 database like so:

```
public static DefaultTableModel loadTableModel(ResultSet rs)
            throws SQLException {

    // names of columns
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
    int columnCount = Definitions.COLUMN_NAMES.length;
    for (String string : Definitions.COLUMN_NAMES) {
        columnNames.add(string);
    }

    // data of table
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
            if (rs.getObject(columnIndex).getClass() == Integer.class) {
                if ((int) rs.getObject(columnIndex) == 0) {
                    vector.add(null);
                } else {
                    vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
                }
            } else {
                vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
            }
        }

        data.add(vector);
    }

    return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

}
```

By doing so I pass over the `data` from my database and `columnNames` to the constructor of the `DefaulTableModel`. The problem is, that not all my columns contain the same data type (seemingly the default type seems to be String), so I need to set the data type for all columns directly while creating the `DefaultTableModel`. How can this be don? I did not find a method to change the column class later on.

If I create my own "`TableModelClass`" that extends `DefaultTableModel`, how do I need to create a constructor that works something like this:

```
TableModelClass(data, columnNames, columnType)
```

> columnType should be a vector containing the Class types like
>   `String.class`, `Boolean.class` etc.

Answer (score 0):

ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();

probably is info You expected. Call only once while openning, metadata is ok when zero rows is in query result too.

BTW I usually

1. build kind of "table metadata" like human readable column captions (Polish language).
2. be aware at null in some rows (You are ok)
3. I use traditionally `Map< String,OBject >` but vector is good to.

copy & paste from my real code, this sample is from web (Wicket) but data modelling is the same.

```
protected Map<String, Object> move_fields() {
    Map<String, Object> rec = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    // MathContext mc = new MathContext(2);

    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        String key;
        try {
            key = md.getColumnName(i + 1).toLowerCase();
            int type = md.getColumnType(i + 1);
            Object o;
            switch (type) {
            case java.sql.Types.DOUBLE:
            case java.sql.Types.DECIMAL:
            case java.sql.Types.FLOAT:
            case java.sql.Types.NUMERIC:
                BigDecimal bd = rs.getBigDecimal(i + 1);
                if (bd != null) {
                    // bd = bd.round(mc);
                    bd = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
                }
                o = bd;
                break;
            default:
                o = rs.getObject(i + 1);
                break;
            }
            rec.put(key, o);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    for (Entry<String, DynamicField> v : virtuals.entrySet()) {
        v.getValue().prepare(rs, record, _my_has_next);

        Object o = v.getValue().getValue(rs, record, _my_has_next);
        rec.put(v.getValue().getNameInTemplate(), o);
    }
    for (Entry<String, String>  f: rest.entrySet()) {
        String kolumna = f.getKey();
        String prawo = f.getValue();
        if(prawa.contains(prawo)){
            int c=1;
        }
        else{
        record.put(kolumna, "");
        }
    }
    return rec;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you give me a small example / code snippet, because I am not sure if I understood you right.

Comment: Code has extra solutions, will not compile. But maybe be helpful :)

Comment: "prawo" -> "right" some columns are left/right aligned,  Metadata is probably indexed from 1.

Comment: WARNING: my database in this fragment has not few type, i.e. Date fields etc, You must add code.

Comment: Looks fine to me, but why do you have your switch with all the cases there and only use the ```java.sql.Types.NUMERIC``` case?

Comment: I have not all option in switch too. My ancient database hasn't and never will class DATE field. You code is for "one shot" of for long term use? Suggest long term thinking.

Comment: WARNING2 some types on some servers/jdbc drivers are convertible or not, MS-SQL can read real/double db column as BigDecimal but others I don't know.

Comment: After trying your suggestion out, I am sorry to tell you that this does not help me. This does not set the column class correctly. See my testing code here: http://pastebin.com/tHYcqP5y

Comment: @flatron `rs.String getColumnClassName(int column)
                          throws SQLException`

Returns the fully-qualified name of the Java class whose instances are manufactured if the method ResultSet.getObject is called to retrieve a value from the column. ResultSet.getObject may return a subclass of the class returned by this method. ... but maybe I'm don't understand exercise (seems be school, I never meet such requirements in production)

Comment: from String class name to full Class use `cls = Class.forName(s)` Continuation of previous: trust to such returned class like You said is good intellectual work, but not so much in practice